# Can you please help me understand the sentence given below from the pagagraph?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I couldn't make the sense out of it.

**“And too, because within the capitol building of a big, industrial state, one sees every day the face of a nation in constant conversation: inner-city mothers and corn and bean farmers, immigrant day laborers alongside suburban investment bankers—all jostling to be heard, all ready to tell their stories.”**

Excerpt From: Barack Obama. “Dreams from My Father.”

[image]

Comment: Read the previous sentence first (Nonetheless...........) and then read your yellow sentence but replace 'too' with 'also'.

Comment: "The face of a nation" – represented by the wide variety of people from all walks of life to be seen in the state Capitol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sentence expresses how important is the capitol building in order to understand and observe people from all walks of life. The people at capitol building are from different sections/strata of the society like young mothers, farmers, laborers and even investment bankers.

The author wants to hear the stories of their lives and understand the lifestyle of the people of that area.